# No puedo hacer Debug .NET

Tags: c#, .net, depuración

Estoy teniendo un problema con el debug en mi visual studio, tengo un proyecto C# que hasta hace un par de días me funcionaba el debug, podía hacer cambios en debug, pero ahora no toma ningún cambio. Ya no sé que hacer, lo último que hice fue una actualización de visual, no sé si sea por eso, cree un nuevo proyecto pero es igual.

En las propiedades del proyecto, tengo habilitado que se pueda editar y continuar.

Es Visual Studio 2019.

[image: Esta imagen es como se ve el debug después de un cambio.]
[image: Configuración proyecto]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, restablecí todas las configuraciones y funcionó

Answer (score 0):

El error lo resolví realizando lo que menciona la documentación aquí:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/general-debugging-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2019

Tan sencillo como esto:
Herramientas > Configuración de importación y exportación > Restablecer todas las configuraciones.

No sé si sea la mejor solución, pero me funcionó y puedo continuar trabajando sin problemas, gracias a todos.

Comment: Por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada. Servirá para que otros que se vean en situación similar lo tengan presente y lo intenten.

Comment: Dice que puedo aceptar mi propia respuesta sólo en dos días más, pero lo haré cuando me lo permita, gracias

Comment: Gracias a ti! y, de paso Bienvenido a [es.so] Ah!, no olvides revisar [ask] las preguntas con énfasis en imágenes no suelen ser bien recibidas. Aunque este caso parecía ameritarlo.